# Generators and "yield" outside the browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, mozilla, rhino

This is snippet is found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators), in an MDN article describing generators and iterators in JavaScript.

```
function simpleGenerator(){  
  yield "first";  
  yield "second";  
  yield "third";  
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)  
    yield i;  
}  

var g = simpleGenerator();  
print(g.next()); // prints "first"  
print(g.next()); // prints "second"  
print(g.next()); // prints "third"  
print(g.next()); // prints 0  
print(g.next()); // prints 1  
print(g.next()); // prints 2  
print(g.next()); // StopIteration is thrown
```

Above that we read:

> The yield keyword is only available to code blocks in HTML wrapped in a

```
<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7">
```

> block (or higher version).

Indeed, the snippet works fine when embedded in an HTML file and included in the aforementioned tag. The problem is, I tried it in Rhino and it doesn't seem to work outside HTML and the browser.

So how can I use generators outside the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_Rhino_1.7R1#JavaScript_1.7_features

> To enable JavaScript 1.7 support, you must set the version as 170 using the `Context.setLanguageVersion()` API call. If you are using the Rhino shell, you can specify `-version 170` on the command line or call `version(170)` in code executed by the shell.

Comment: Thank you, hadn't noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

To change context:

```
            Context ctx = Context.enter();
            ctx.setLanguageVersion(Context.VERSION_1_7);
            try {

             CompilerEnvirons compEnv = new CompilerEnvirons();
             compEnv.initFromContext(ctx);

             ...

            }
            finally { Context.exit(); }
```